# Generate .mat of Images - Matlab

Tags: matlab, mat-file

How can I create a `.mat` file which holds a bunch of images in matlab?

I'm using the images as a training set, so figured it would be easier to load from a `.mat` than load 100+ images every time I run the program.

If I'm thinking about this the wrong way, please point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Create a 4D Matrix and store that into the mat file? If the sizes of the images are different, use cell matrices.

Comment: Any already written code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply combine all images (each of which is a `3D` matrix for color images) into a `4D` matrix with last dimension is the total number. And save this `4D` matrix to a `.mat` file for later loading.

For grayscale images, you only need to combine them into a `3D` matrix as each of which is `2D`.

As commented by @Divakar, you may need to combine them into a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) if the sizes of the images are not consistent.

---

**Edit:** Suppose you have combined the images into a `3D/4D` matrix called `data`, you can use `save data;` to save it into disk and use `load data;` to load it back.

Comment: Is that just an array of 3d matrices if they're the same size? and using a cell array if they images differ?

Comment: @Reanimation Yes. Each one is a 3D. You can combine them into a 4D.

Comment: Ok thanks guys. I'll give it a shot in matlab. Is there a function to export a 4D matrice as a file?

Comment: Thanks. This source helped also. http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/answers/17692-creating-mat-file